# How to read units from a column in a table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I read in a csv into a table and set each column's units with VariableUnits. I would like to be able to read the units for a certain column (say column 3, "Temp"). I would like to know if the temperature was recorded in degrees F or C or K.

I can  use table{1,1}.Properties.VariableUnits to display the units for all the columns, but I can't figure out how to look up the units for just one column.

Also if I want to update the units for one column, how can I do that as well?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that calling the column at the end of the statement is the way to reference the column.

```
table{1,1}.Properties.VariableUnits{column_name}
```

Is the way to get the column information.